# Podcast # 6 - Quotes

Tags: discussion, podcast

[This episode](https://soundcloud.com/user9210836/skeptics-se-podcast-episode-6) focuses on Quotes.

Although we do allow it on Skeptics, generally this kind of questions is hard to answer. They are too often false claims, and it is a case of trying to assert a negative position. That said, we get a lot of of these types of questions, so it is only fair that we cover this topic.

## Questions

- [Did Bill Gates say that vaccines and health care could reduce the population growth by 10-15%?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/31042/did-bill-gates-say-that-vaccines-and-health-care-could-reduce-the-population-gro)
- [Did Einstein say this about his marriage?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/34322/did-einstein-say-this-about-his-marriage)
- [Did Ray Bradbury ever claim that "Fahrenheit 451" was not about censorship?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/27821/did-ray-bradbury-ever-claim-that-fahrenheit-451-was-not-about-censorship)
- [Did Bill Gates say 640k ought to be enough for everyone?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2863/did-bill-gates-say-640k-ought-to-be-enough-for-everyone)

## Hot Questions

- [Are thousands of Islamic terrorists entering the United States?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/34792/are-thousands-of-islamic-terrorists-entering-the-united-states)
- [Did Augustine of Hippo warn Christians to beware mathematicians?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/34756/did-augustine-of-hippo-warn-christians-to-beware-mathematicians)
- [Are refugees in the UK holidaying in the countries they fled from?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/34863/are-refugees-in-the-uk-holidaying-in-the-countries-they-fled-from)

## User Shout Outs

[Top Users](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=week): 
        Tim, rougon, Avery, gerrit

[Welcome New user](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=NewUsers&sort=creationdate): 
        Pierre B

- Do any of you want to join us for a podcast? We would be very
  happy to extend an invitation to any listener who gets in
  contact with us.
- We are always open to feedback, so don't hesitate to contact us
- Is there any specific subject you want us to look into? Send us
  suggestions.